# finding minimum in a column based on a unique id in r

Tags: r, excel, minimum

Need some help with a simple r command to do something that is done through pivots in excel.
I have a table with 2 variables ID and date. I need a command that can create a dataframe which has the unique list of these IDs and the minimum date against the ID.

for example, say my data frame is transpose of (ID list is col 1 and Date2 are in col 2)

```
ID:    ID1 ID1 ID2 ID2 ID3
Date: Mar 01 Mar 02 Mar03 Mar 04 Mar 05
```

I need a data frame that gives

```
ID1  Mar01
ID2  Mar03
ID3  Mar05
```

Comment: Could you post the data you actually have? Are the IDs and dates independent vectors? `dput()` is your friend...

Comment: Please also show us the code you have tried and why it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to use `as.Date` for the date datatype and use one of the formats given there see `?format.Date` for format types. Lets create an example of input table:
`df_input<-data.frame(ID=sample(1:5), Date=as.Date(sample(c("2012-10-03", "2012-11-03", "2012-12-03"), size= 5,replace=T)))`
Now use `sort` to sort your input data frame. Like:
`sort(df_input$Date)`

Have a great day! Also, if you need help importing the file try this :[Unable to import data from a sample Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506019/unable-to-import-data-from-a-sample-excel-file)

Comment: The OPs example has repeating IDs; and they want to select a subset of the data, not just sort it, I think. Why make a new example when there's one there already?

Comment: :) I missed that point! But can be fixed through `duplicated()`. I'll wait for OP's comments before posting further.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my interpretation of this.

You're starting with a `data.frame` that looks like this. (I've added an extra out-of-order value to the `data.frame` so my answer will be different from yours).

```
mydf <- data.frame(ID = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID2", "ID2", "ID3", "ID3"),
                   Date = c("Mar 01", "Mar 02", "Mar 03", "Mar 04", "Mar 05", "Mar 04"))
mydf
#    ID   Date
# 1 ID1 Mar 01
# 2 ID1 Mar 02
# 3 ID2 Mar 03
# 4 ID2 Mar 04
# 5 ID3 Mar 05
# 6 ID3 Mar 04
```

First, create actual "date" objects out of your "Date" column. I've assumed your date format is "mon day", so I've used `"%b %d"` in `strptime`. Since there is no year, the current year is assumed.

```
Date2 <- strptime(mydf$Date, format="%b %d")  ## ASSUMES THE CURRENT YEAR
Date2
# [1] "2013-03-01" "2013-03-02" "2013-03-03" "2013-03-04" "2013-03-05" "2013-03-04"
```

Next, find a function that lets us order these dates by your "ID" variable. In base R, `ave` does that pretty conveniently.

```
ave(as.numeric(Date2), mydf$ID, FUN = order)
# [1] 1 2 1 2 2 1
```

Use those values to subset rows with the first (lowest) value for each ID (that is, where the result is equal to "1").

```
mydf[ave(as.numeric(Date2), mydf$ID, FUN = order) == 1, ]
#    ID   Date
# 1 ID1 Mar 01
# 3 ID2 Mar 03
# 6 ID3 Mar 04
```